# python - subprocess' check_output - return shell message

Tags: python, shell

Here is my code:

```
from subprocess import check_output
print check_output('whoami', shell=True)
```

This works fine.

However, if I put a command that isnt' existent it will say:

```
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
CalledProcessError: Command 'test' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

When if you were to run this on your shell, it would say something like:

```
'test' isnot recognized as an intenral or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

How can I get this instead?

Comment: It's much more robust to use [`check_call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) which gives you a clear indication of a failure instead of having to look at the text.  As to your question -- if you want the shell, use the `shell`.

Comment: You can use `proc = subprocess.Popen('test', shell=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read in the [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) documentation:

> If the return code was non-zero it raises a `CalledProcessError`. The `CalledProcessError` object will have the return code in the returncode attribute and any output in the output attribute.

So you can do this:

```
import subprocess

try:
    print subprocess.check_output('test', shell=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError, e:
    print e.output
```